# Liveness/Readiness probe failure for bitnami/zookeeper and bitnami/kafka image

Tags: kubernetes, apache-zookeeper, readinessprobe, livenessprobe

I am trying to add liveness and readinessprobe for zookeeper using bitnami/zookeeper image, but the pod creation is failing, please let me know what values need to be added in liveness and readiness probe.

Below is the value that I have tried with.

```
livenessProbe:
      enabled: true
      initialDelaySeconds: 120
      periodSeconds: 30
      timeoutSeconds: 5
      failureThreshold: 6
      successThreshold: 1
readinessProbe:
      enabled: true
      initialDelaySeconds: 120
      periodSeconds: 30
      timeoutSeconds: 5
      failureThreshold: 6
      successThreshold: 1
```

I am getting the below error.

[spec.containers[0].livenessProbe: Required value: must specify a handler type, spec.containers[0].readinessProbe: Required value: must specify a handler type]

Answer (score 1):

The Kubernetes Probes as the livenessProbe and readinessProbe require a `handler` which is used for the probe. Kubernetes supports multiple handler types, e.g. a [HTTP request probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-http-request) or a [liveness command probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-command). There are additional handler types, e.g. `TCP probes`.
You can find all supported handler types in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/).
Please note that the handler configuration is required and there isn't a default handler type.

Comment: To add to this answer: Zookeeper has a built-in mechanism to check it's liveness/readiness, by issuing `zookeeper-ready 2181` command. You can read more [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/zookeeper/)

Comment: I tried with zookeeper-ready, didn't work for me, is it due to the image that I am using? I am using bitnami/zookeeper image. In the document the image shown as k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-zookeeper:1.0-3.4.10

Comment: @p10l any idea for bitnami/zookeeper image, which script to be used for healthCheck. As with zookeeper-ready script it is not working.